# Can someone help me figure out why my ul isn't turning into horizontal navigation? thanks :)

Tags: html, css

In the HTML below, I am trying to create horizontal navigation using an unordered list (`ul`). I tries using W3Schools as a guide, but it doesn't seem to be working; I'm sure I am just overlooking something.

[Here's what it is supposed to look like, and what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHZrd.jpg). The coloring and such isn't a concern right now.

Below is the relevant code I'm using. The `ul` is nested in the body. I would assume the rest of my CSS isn't affecting this but I could be wrong.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="Employment.html">Employment</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Company.html">Company</a></li>
</ul>




body {
font: normal normal normal 75%/1.3em verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans- 
serif; text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
font: normal normal normal 100/2em verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans- 
serif; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; list-style: none; 
text-decoration: none; text-align: center;
}


h1 {
font: normal normal normal 140%/1.3em 
verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
font: normal normal normal 120%/1.3em 
verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans-serif; text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul {
display: inline-block; list-style-type: none;
font: normal normal normal 90%/2em verdana,geneva,lucida,arial,sans- 
serif; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only CSS that you have provided that effects the `ul` is the `.nav` class. So don't worry about any of the other code.

The problem is that you have put `display:inline-block` on the `.nav` element. You actually want this on the children. You can do this by selecting `.nav li`.

```css
.nav {
  font: normal normal normal 100/2em verdana, geneva, lucida, arial, sans-serif; 
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="Employment.html">Employment</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Company.html">Company</a></li>
</ul>
```

That being said, you may find that using `flexbox` will be much more rewarding. It will automatically adjust the spacing of the child elements. Check out the [CSS-Tricks Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more info.

```css
.nav {
  font: normal normal normal 100/2em verdana, geneva, lucida, arial, sans-serif; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="Employment.html">Employment</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Company.html">Company</a></li>
</ul>
```